# Return True or False from dict list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
name = [{'a':'Open'},{'b':'Pending'},{'c':'Completed'}]
[s.get('c') == 'Completed' for s in name if 'Completed' in s.values()][0]
```

Output is `True` when the list comprehension has `Completed`. 
How can this return `False` when `Rejected` is provided in the above list comprehension.

```
[True if 'Completed' in s.values() else False for s in name]
```

I have tried this and this returns `[False, False, True]`, instead I want `True` or `False`.

Is it possible using a list comprehension?

Comment: What if both Tina and Rick is in there?

Comment: I think you are better off not using list comprehension since the result you want isn't a list in both scenarios.

Comment: Also, in your first example, you are only checking for key `'c'` in each element of list `name`. So if `'Completed'` is paired with a different key, you will not get `True`.

Comment: Did you try `sum()`? like `sum([True if 'Completed' in s.values() else False for s in name]) > 0`

Comment: @hemnathmouli Sum works, Perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: `any()` with a generator is better than `sum()`, since `any()` will shortcut on the first answer, but `sum()` has to check them all, even if you use a generator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List comprehensions are supposed to return *lists*. You could use a generator expression and just stop on the first result, like

```
next((True for s in name if 'Completed' in s.values()), False)
```

Or you could use `any()` on you list comprehension.

```
any([True if 'Completed' in s.values() else False for s in name])
```

Which really could be simplified to

```
any('Completed' in s.values() for s in name)
```

which again uses a generator expression so you don't have to generate the whole list in advance. `any()` will stop at the first true result when given an iterator.

Comment: the last answer will be very useful in case if it is a bigger list!! Thank you!

Comment: This is assuming there are only two cases `Completed` and `Completed not present`. Doesn't explicitly checks for `Rejected` case. Good answer tho'.